# (Python Lex-Yacc Dealing With Ambiguous Grammars) Applying Math precedence rules on string query

Tags: python, yacc, lex

I'm new to Lex-Yacc, I have a Python Lex-Yacc Parser for parsing string query.
Its working fine with precedence rules as:

```
self.precedence = (
            ('left', 'AND', 'OR', 'NOT'),
        )

self.parser = yacc.yacc(module=self, debug=debug, write_tables=debug)
```

but i want to add additional steps to follow precedence rules with additional parenthesis.
For example:

```
query1 = expression OR expression AND expression OR expression  
query2 = expression OR expression AND ( expression OR expression )
```

into:

```
query1 = expression OR ( expression AND expression ) OR expression 
query2 = expression OR ( expression AND ( expression OR expression ))
```

How can achieve these steps?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need precedence rules to handle parentheses. Parentheses are unambiguous. You need to fix your original precedence rule to put the three operators in different precedence levels. As written, the declaration says that all operators are at the same level, associating left-to-right.

Compare that with the usual precedence declaration for algebraic expressions, which you'll find in the calculator example.  There, `+` and `-` are in one group, and `*` and `/` in a different one, so that multiplication binds more tightly than addition.